# JavaFX drag & drop with custom node beside mouse icon

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

What's the best way to show a semi-transparent "copy" of a Node next to the mouse icon during a drag/drop?

Basically I have HBoxes with colored backgrounds and text labels in them, and I'd like to give the appearance that they "stick" to the mouse cursor when they're being dragged.

It's nice if users can visually verify WHAT they're dragging, rather than just seeing the mouse cursor change into the various drag icons.  Scene Builder tends to do this when you drag some components, like a RadioButton.

Comment: Are you doing a "platform-supported drag and drop" (i.e. you are calling `startDragAndDrop` on a node at some point)? If so, you can just call `Dragboard.setDragView(...)` to set the image cursor for the drag.

Comment: Just internal, nothing outside the application window.

Comment: That's not what I asked.

Comment: It wasn't clear to me what you mean by "platform supported". I take that to mean dragging to/from an OS-platform desktop or folder, which I'm not doing. startDragAndDrop is being called on one of the HBox Nodes, like in the answer below.

Comment: There are [three different dragging modes in JavaFX](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/input/MouseEvent.html): "simple press-drag-release" (the default), "full press-drag release" (initiated with a call to `startFullDrag`) and "platform supported drag-and-drop" (initiated with call to `startDragAndDrop`). The solution outlined below only works with the third option; but there's no way of knowing from your question that that is what you are doing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "semi-transparent "copy" of a Node" is accomplished by calling `snapshot(null, null)` on a node, which returns a `WritableImage`. Then you set this `WritableImage` as the drag view of the `DragBoard`. Here is a small example on how to do this:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.input.ClipboardContent;
import javafx.scene.input.DataFormat;
import javafx.scene.input.Dragboard;
import javafx.scene.input.TransferMode;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class DragAndDrop extends Application {
    private static final DataFormat DRAGGABLE_HBOX_TYPE = new DataFormat("draggable-hbox");

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        VBox content = new VBox(5);

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            Label label = new Label("Test drag");

            DraggableHBox box = new DraggableHBox();
            box.getChildren().add(label);

            content.getChildren().add(box);
        }

        stage.setScene(new Scene(content));
        stage.show();
    }

    class DraggableHBox extends HBox {
        public DraggableHBox() {
            this.setOnDragDetected(e -> {
                Dragboard db = this.startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.MOVE);

                // This is where the magic happens, you take a snapshot of the HBox.
                db.setDragView(this.snapshot(null, null));

                // The DragView wont be displayed unless we set the content of the dragboard as well. 
                // Here you probably want to do more meaningful stuff than adding an empty String to the content.
                ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();
                content.put(DRAGGABLE_HBOX_TYPE, "");
                db.setContent(content);

                e.consume();
            });
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

Comment: Heh, didn't know you could pass (null, null) to snapshot because I didn't RTFM far enough... ah well, this works anyway.